# Render data once from API call in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, axios

I'm building an app with React Native and having trouble showing the results from an API call.

```
function getRecipes() {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = React.useState([]);

  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/recipes')
    .then(response => {
      var data = response.data.map((recipe: Object) => recipe)
      setRecipes(data);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  return recipes
};

export default function Recipes({ navigation }: Props) {
  const recipes = getRecipes();
  console.log(recipes)

  return (
      ...other code
      <View>
        {recipes}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

[image: console.log(recipes)]

`console.log(recipes)` returns the result of the API request over and over, I only need it once. How can I use the function `getRecipes` to return just one instance of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing stems from the fact that the `getRecipes` function is called each time the Recipes component is rendered; because `axios.get` is asynchronous, this means that rendering occurs before the API call is finished, which leads to multiple `console.log(recipes)` executions as the component re-renders.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Recipes({ navigation }: Props) {

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/recipes');
        const data = response.data.map((recipe: Object) => recipe);
        setRecipes(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    fetchData();

  }, []);

  console.log(recipes)

  return (
      ...other code
      <View>
        {recipes}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Here the recipes are stored in the component's state using `setRecipes`, and are mapped over to render the components in the JSX. The `useEffect` hook is used to conduct the API call when the component mounts (`[]` as the dependency array guarantees it only runs once).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I think my idea of how to use the component was wrong. I wanted to have a recipe component that handled various things, but it sounds like I need a main component that then loads other components, like this one. I would like clarification on the rendering though -- I'm only navigating to it once, but does the component just constantly render waiting for a state change?

Comment: Hi Mirando, The problem stems from the fact that the getRecipes function is called each time the Recipes component renders; this is why you see multiple log statements in the console. The console.log(recipes) statement is placed directly after the call to getRecipes, and because it is outside any useEffect or asynchronous context, it gets executed each time the Recipes component renders.

Comment: yes I understand that piece. What I don't understand is how I'm rendering the recipe component? All I'm doing is navgating to the recipe component via the native navigation component. Is the navigation container constantly rendering?

Comment: Since your current code snippet does not provide the full context of your navigation setup. Generally, in a React Native application, components within a navigation container, such as those using React Navigation, are re-rendered when the navigation state changes.

Comment: Yes it’s only navigating there on button click, that’s all. I’ll post another question if I can’t resolve

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you in get your recipe data render only once

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Recipes({ navigation }: Props) {
    
    const [recipes, setRecipes] = React.useState([]); /* hooks are always inside functional tsx Component */

    function getRecipes() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/recipes')
            .then(response => {
                var data = response.data.map((recipe: Object) => recipe)
                setRecipes(data);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        return recipes
    };
    /* To Call funtions once after component we use useEffect hook */
    useEffect(() => {
        getRecipes()
    }, [])
    console.log(recipes)

    return (
        ...other code
        <View>
        { recipes.length > 0 && recipes }
        </View >
      </View >
    );
};
```